# Using Import * from single export

Tags: javascript

I am not used to seeing a `import *` often

The react + readux code I am going through uses `import *`

According to firefox documentation about `import *`

> This inserts myModule into the current scope, containing all the
>   exports from the module in the file located in /modules/my-module.js.

suppose we have an export statement like this in our code (call it articleTypes.js) .

```
export const ARTICLES_FETCHED = 'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED';
```

Doing this, Would make actually probably make sense we didn't use export default above

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
```

But If we alter the above lines like this

```
export default const ARTICLES_FETCHED = 'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED';
```

and do something like this

```
 import types from './actionTypes'
```

Will it work the same way as the above code? or will this actually work? and will this be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

> But If we alter the above lines like this
>
> ```
> export default const ARTICLES_FETCHED = 'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED';
> ```
>
> and do something like this
>
> ```
> import types from './actionTypes'
> ```
>
> Will it work the same way as the above code?
>   Will it work the same way as the above code?

No, `types` would be equal to `'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED'`

On the other hand, this module:

```
export default {ARTICLES_FETCHED: 'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED'}
```

would act the same as this module:

```
export const ARTICLES_FETCHED = 'articles.ARTICLES_FETCHED'
```

The main benefit from using `import * as myVar from 'module'` is that you get all the exports from `module` wrapped up in a neat variable `myVar`.

Comment: Also, never default-export object literals.